# Shadow Map in RenderMonkey

Tags: 3d, rendermonkey

I'm trying to create a shader that generates a shadow on a terrain, for a teapot. I have it working, for the most part, though I'm having a strange issue where I have a main shadow, but also lots of smaller teapot shadows. And it's kind of leaving me stumped.

I've uploaded my project to DropBox, and you can download it [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12763956/ShadowMap.rfx). Can anyone give me any pointers?

Comment: Hey! So I know this was asked a long time ago, but did you manage to fix it? Because I want to do the same thing and am also having issues and would appreciate any tips!

Comment: Unfortunately I did not. I moved on from working on this project a few weeks after posting this.